# Permanent ical feed for Outlook 365 Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-365

How do I get a permanent URL or local file location with an up-to-date `.ical` export of my Office365 calendar?

- I'm looking for an alternative to manually saving a snapshot of my calendar, as that's not a solution
- This would allow showing the current/next meeting info on my Stream Deck via a [plugin](https://www.reddit.com/r/streamdeckprofiles/comments/lp9vz0/stream_deck_ical_plugin/)

Comment: It is not feasible to keep the .ical file up-to-date. When we export the calendar to .ical, it is static data and it cannot be up-to-date. Or you could contact with Stream Deck, and check if it can work with the email account directly.

Comment: Have you tried sharing/publishing the calendar to get a URL for it? If this is what you're looking for, I can create an answer for it: **WebMail:** _Settings_ → _Calendar_ → _Shared Calendars_ || **Outlook**: Calendar tab → Right-click calendar name → _Sharing Permissions_

Comment: Hi @JW0914, thanks for the hint! Didn't find it in Outlook desktop, however you are right there's a way in Webmail. Feel free to post this as an answer and I'll accept.

https://i.imgur.com/Gem9FfX.png

It answers the question, only downside is it shares calendar content online using only 'magic' URL security and no additional auth - but that's my problem.